# My bios will not recegnise Ubuntu as a valid os now

Tags: boot

I downloaded the ISO and burned it to a dvd. Restarted the Laptop and the bios tells me that Ubuntu is now an invalid OS. Is there some special thing you have to do to get it to boot now? I have had ubuntu on other Thinkpads before.

Comment: check the md5sum of the downloaded iso.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the new thinkpad is attempting to use UEFI boot, but that some setting is causing it to accept only Windows (this shouldn't happen, but my own laptop will only load Windows 8 by UEFI because it appears to be using some broken custom implementation.  This despite the fact that there's an MIT-licensed UEFI implementation out there, which most manufacturers use.  But I digress).  To test this, try making sure UEFI is disabled (it should be safe to change this temporarily) in the BIOS settings, then booting from the CD.  If that works, then thou'lt at least know where the problem lies...

Comment: My bios does not have that option. Before I have to change the SATA mode to Compatibility mode for it to install/boot.

Comment: If there are no "OS selection" or "UEFI" options, then we can at least eliminate that possibility.  I would, however, be *very* surprised if a newish machine needed its SATA mode to be set to IDE emulation (which is what Compatibility usually means, with the other option being AHCI) in order to boot.  I would suggest than @AvinashRaj's suggestion of checking the downloaded ISO is a very good plan.  Also to ensure that the ISO was correctly burned to the DVD, rather than just placed as a file on it.